# How to determine the index number of the last object in a NSMutable Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutable Array and was trying to find the index number of the last object in this array. I tried this, but it feels cumbersome:

```
 int currentCount = [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:currentNoteBookNumber] tabColours] count];
    NSLog(@"Number of tab colours total: %i", currentCount);
NSLog(@"Index number of last object: %i", currentCount-1);
```

Is there another way of doing this? The context of my problem is that I need to determine the last object in order to change it:

```
replaceObjectAtIndex:[last object] withObject: ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need the index, then that is the way to do it (`int lastIndex = [array count] - 1;`).  If you just want to replace the last object with a different object however, you can do:

```
[array removeLastObject];
[array addObject: newLastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[myArray count]-1 withObject:someNewObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
int lastIndex = [YOUR_ARRAY count] - 1;
```

this will gives you last `index`  of your `array`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add objects to your `NSMutableArray` with `addObjects:` method it always put elements at the end. When you `removeObjectAtIndex:index` it automatically shift down on 1 position all elements with indexes > `index`. That is why the last object in array is always have index `[array count] - 1`. I do not tell you about replacing objects, I just tell about adding objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index=[*yourarrayname* indexOfObject:[*yourarrayname* lastObject]];
NSLog(@"index=%d",index);
```